# Trouble using glTexSubImage2D with a pixel buffer object

Tags: opengl, textures, texture2d

I am trying to upload a subset of my image to the texture. So, I do as follows:

```
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureId);
glBindBuffer(GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER, buffer);

glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ROW_LENGTH, width);
glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_SKIP_PIXELS, x_offset);
glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_SKIP_ROWS, y_offset);

glTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, x_offset, y_offset, width, height,
                GL_BGRA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL);

glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ROW_LENGTH, 0);
glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_SKIP_PIXELS, 0);
glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_SKIP_ROWS, 0);
```

This code works fine when x and y offsets are set to 0 and the width and height are set to the texture width and height. However, whenever I try a subset, I can completely rubbish image which looks like noise.

I can understand a part of my texture being noisy as it would not be initialized with proper values (due to the code only reading a subset) but I expected that block representing the subset to have the proper values.

Comment: What's the dimensions of the image in the unpack buffer? You have to set the unpack row length and skips only if the image you want to unpack from is larger than the source rectangle you want to take the pixels from to replace the destination with.

Comment: The dimensions of the pbo buffer is bigger than the rectangle formed by (offset, offset, width, height) if I understand your question correctly? In the worst case, I will copy the whole object which would then be equal to the PBO buffer dimensions.

Comment: Ok, in that case the unpack row length must be the width of the image in the PBO. Not the width of the to-be-copied rectangle (in your code both dimensions are equal).

Comment: ahhhhhh...ok, I will have to wait till tomorrow to try this. I think I also need to set the data offset correctly in the last parameter.

Comment: @datenwolf Can I ask if glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1) is also needed?

Comment: It's always a good idea to set the unpack alignment. The initial value is 4 and depending on your image's dimensions that may not fit. And then other parts of the program may set the value and not restore it (same deal as with setting the viewport and projection in paintGL and not resizeGL).

Comment: Thanks for your help! That did the job. I had the wrong width. Should have read the docs more carefully.